# Make event-emitter synchronous

Tags: javascript

I am trying out the package [proxy-lists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-lists#getproxies), which uses an event emitter to receive proxies.

I created the following example:

```
const ProxyLists = require('proxy-lists');

function main() {

    const options = {
        countries: null
    };

    // `gettingProxies` is an event emitter object.
    const gettingProxies = ProxyLists.getProxies(options);

    let data = []
    gettingProxies.on('data', function (proxies) {
        console.log(proxies);
        data.push(proxies)
        if (data.length > 1000) {
            return data
        }
    });
}

console.log("First Call");
const res = main()
console.log(res);
console.log("Last Call");
```

However, I receive the following output:

```
First Call
undefined
Last Call
[ { ipAddress: 'ip-192-169-156-211.ip.secureserver.net',
    port: 52324,
    country: null,
    source: 'rosinstrument' },
  { ipAddress: 'ip-192-169-218-61.ip.secureserver.net',
```

As you can see the `console.log`'s are already called when the function is running. However, I would prefer the following *synchronous* order:

```
First Call
[ { ipAddress: '72.89.213.193.static.cust.telenor.com',
    port: 51024,
    country: 'us',
    source: 'rosinstrument' },
  { ipAddress: '50.250.56.129',
    port: 48380,
    country: 'us',
    source: 'rosinstrument' },
...
Last Call
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *"Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?"* You have wrong expectations. You cannot make an asynchronous process synchronous. You can rearrange your code to make these calls sequential though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ES7's [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax to make your asynchronous code *appear* as synchronous code:

```
const ProxyLists = require('proxy-lists');

function getProxies() {
    const options = {
        countries: null
    };

    // `gettingProxies` is an event emitter object.
    const gettingProxies = ProxyLists.getProxies(options);

    let data = []
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // wrap in promise
        gettingProxies.on('data', function (proxies) {
            console.log(proxies);
            data.push(proxies)
            if (data.length > 1000) {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    }); 
}

async function main() {
    console.log("First Call");
    const res = await getProxies();
    console.log(res); // can be used
    console.log("Last Call");
}

main();
```

Here I have made `main()` an `async` function which allows me to use to the `await` keyword which essentially gets the resolved value (ie: `data`) from the `Promise` returned by the `getProxies()` method. In the background, this is essentially just syntactic sugar for `.then()`, and so it is still asynchronous code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could wrap the asynchronous code into a `Promise` and `resolve` it with the value you're waiting for, and `then` call the next code you need, something like this:

```
const ProxyLists = require('proxy-lists');

function main() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            countries: null
        };

        // `gettingProxies` is an event emitter object.
        const gettingProxies = ProxyLists.getProxies(options);

        let data = []

        gettingProxies.on('data', function (proxies) {
            console.log(proxies);
            data.push(proxies)
            if (data.length > 1000) {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    })
}

console.log("First Call");

main().then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log("Last Call");
})
```

if you're working with something like babel or typescript, you could even use `async`/`await` like this other way:

```
console.log("First Call");
var res = await main();
console.log(res);
console.log("Last Call");
```